# Retrieve specific value from a jsonb object postgres 11

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb-array-elements

I have the following jsonb column in my table `requests` called tasks

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         id  |           tasks                                                                                                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1           | [{"name":"Pick up","order":0,"end_at":null,"start_at":"2022-10-28T13:00:00.000+08:00"}, {"name":"Deliver","order":1,"end_at":"2022-10-28T13:42:00.000+08:00","start_at":"2022-10-28T13:27:00.000+08:00"}] |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Below is a sample of the table and i would like to get the start_at of the first object where order = 0

I could do this easily in postgres 12 but looking for a way to do it in postgres 11

`select (jsonb_path_query_array(jsonb_agg(row_to_json(jb)), '$.tasks[0].start_at'))[0] from requests as jb where id = 1;` This returns `"2022-10-28T13:00:00.000+08:00"`

How can i do this in postgres 11?

I tried using json_agg but could only get to getting the object but not the value
`select to_jsonb(jsonb_agg(row_to_json(jb))->0->'tasks'->>0)->>0 from requests as jb where id = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is even simpler. First flatten the JSONB array.

```sql
select l ->> 'start_at' as start_at 
from requests, lateral jsonb_array_elements(tasks) as l
where l ->> 'order' = '0'
order by l ->> 'start_at' limit 1; -- get the first (oldest) one only
```

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hhX7aaFVfJB3SUeK4YLitw/0)